# How do I get both mouseover events for overlapping svg elements in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, this, mouseover, event-bubbling

I have some trouble with painting two maps on top of each other : one for the counties of Germany, one for the states. I want for both that the mouseover event triggers. Furthermore in the mouseover function **this** shall give me the path.

If I code the following, only the mouseoverSubunit() will trigger:

```
var unitData, subunitData; //json files
var height, width; //integers

var projection = d3.geoAlbers(); 
var path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select("#container").append("svg").attr("width", width).attr("height", height);
var origin = svg.append("g");

origin.selectAll(".unit")
    .data(unitData)
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", function(d) { return "unit " + d.name; })
    .attr("d", path)
    .on("mouseover", mouseoverUnit);

origin.selectAll(".subunit")
    .data(subunitData)
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", function(d) { return "subunit " + d.name; })
    .attr("d", path)
    .on("mouseover", mouseoverSubunit);


mouseoverUnit(){console.log(this)}
mouseoverSubunit(){console.log(this)}
```

Okay, I succeeded to invoke both functions by changing the DOM but here I will get the output < g class="map"> for **this** in mouseoverUnit() and not the paths.

```
origin.append("g").attr("class","map").selectAll(".unit")
    .data(unitData)
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", function(d) { return "unit " + d.name; })
    .attr("d", path);

origin.append("g").attr("class","map").selectAll(".subunit")
    .data(subunitData)
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", function(d) { return "subunit " + d.name; })
    .attr("d", path)
    .on("mouseover", mouseoverSubunit);

d3.selectAll(".map").on("mouseover", mouseoverUnit);
```

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: this.selectAll("path")

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunality, that doesn't work. console.log(this.selectAll("path")) gives nothing.